# How to play wav file in explorer with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm searching for a way to play wav files in my web app that will support internet explorer but cannot find a way to play wav in explorer - anyone figure out how to do it? (without silverlight)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Convert to MP3 and your problem is solved.

Comment: Here is code that seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267316/wav-file-only-playing-on-certain-computers-in-ie-8

Comment: without converting to mp3 of course...

Answer (score 3):

use the [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) element:

```
    var audio = new Audio('c:\\w1.wav');
    audio.play();
```

Comment: I think you should forget INTERNET EXPLORER!! It's so incompatible with new standards ...

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer does not support wav-files using the HTML5 audio-tag.
1)You can try an embed tag:

```
<embed src="path/mywav.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="wavfile"
        enablejavascript="true">
```

2)Or you can try howler.js. A modern web audio js library.

3)Or you can simply try :

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.wav');
audio.play();
```

Comment: when i try 2 and 3 options i get : "MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type"